# Tap-to-wake not working every time

Tags: settings, nokia-lumia-1020

It seems like the tap-to-wake feature on my Lumia 1020 is not very reliable.

Is there any way to make it work more consistently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have set your touch sensitivity to "High".

For some reason, this actually seems to make the phone *less* responsive to tap-to-wake.

Try setting it to "Normal":
<kbd>SETTINGS</kbd> [image] <kbd>SYSTEM</kbd> [image] <kbd>DISPLAY+TOUCH</kbd> [image] <kbd>TOUCH</kbd> [image] <kbd>TOUCH SENSITIVITY</kbd>

Other than that, keep in mind that the two taps must be:

- **In the same location.** *Within a ½" or so.*
- **Short in duration.** *Neither should be more than ¼s.*
- **Short in separation.** *No more than ¼s apart.*
- **But not too quick!** *You must lift your finger to register the end of one tap and the start of another.*

With "Normal" sensitivity and a little practice, you should be able to tap your phone awake every time.